# Synchronous reading of a multipart upload alongside Django

Tags: python, django, multipart, synchronous

I have a Django application which needs to have access to reading multipart file uploads as file-like objects *as they're uploaded,* which means that I need more or less synchronous access to the request object and a way to unpack it in chunks to binary data. Django unfortunately handles uploads by moving them directly into memory or to temporary files, which won't work for my use case.

Some one recommended that I use gevent/greenlet to handle the upload, but I'm not sure how that plays into the equation and what setup is required alongside Django to make it work. Plus, running something outside of Django would mean that I would have to implement a database connection layer to validate that the upload is allowed (using a ticket id).

With this said, how can I set this up? Django should be running in a WSGI application, and someone had also recommended writing a second  WSGI application to capture a single URL path for uploads. I'd like to essentially take as much advantage of the Django framework as I can, while being able to read uploads synchronously?

<sup>(I just became familiar with the `requests` Python library and have to say I'm a pretty big fan, though I wouldn't know the first thing about using it in a server context.)</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe a lot of these suggestions are overcomplicating things.

You need to change the way Django handles uploaded files? Simply modify [the upload handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#upload-handlers).

The [base class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/uploadhandler.py#L56) is relatively straightforward, and gives you lots of great hooks. You should be able to extend it to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't write all the code for you (it's complex), here is my recommended setup.

1. Use Tornado + Django: Tornado can embed WSGI processes, so this gives you the ability to have a single process host both Django, and this one off Tornado handler. Here's a quick sample from one of my active projects (though this using Tornado as a Socket.io handler, it should give you the gist of the solution (:

   ```
   # Socket Server
   db = momoko.Pool(DB_DSN, **DB_CONFIG)
   router   = tornadio2.TornadioRouter(QueryRouter, user_settings={'db':db})
   sock_app = tornado.web.Application(router.urls, flash_policy_port = FL_PORT, flash_policy_file = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'assets/xml/flashpolicy.xml'), socket_io_port = WS_PORT, debug=True)
   # Django Server
   os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'sever.settings'
   application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
   container = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(application)


   # Start the web servers
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       try:
           import logging
           tornado.options.parse_command_line()
           logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
           logging.info('Server started')
           tornado.locale.set_default_locale('us_US')
           http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(container)
           http_server.listen(8000)
           tornadio2.SocketServer(sock_app, auto_start=True)
           tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
       except KeyboardInterrupt:
           tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
           logging.info("Stopping servers.")
   ```

This could easily be converted to two server instances running on two different ports, with 80 being reserved for Django and 8080 being used for your upload handler.

1. I'm recommending Tornado because it supports streaming request body, and is very well suited to this type of use. [Here's a gist that might help you](https://gist.github.com/sarva/1651121).
2. Your proxying setup will matter. If you're using NGINX, make sure to turn proxy_buffering off.
3. I wouldn't use a database for the ticket/upload check. Redis or memcache would probably be a much faster way to handle this. A cache would also be great way to bass upload progress back and forth between Django and Tornado, since the overhead for setting/getting a new value would be so small.

This is a big hairy problem that will serious engineering to come up with something elegant, but it's more than doable.

Comment: Has Tornado incorporated that streaming request body patch? It looks like the code mentioned in the Gist actually uses a fork of Tornado which might not be committed back into the main repo.

Comment: Not 100% sure. You may have to fork it and apply the patch to your fork. Not a huge deal.

Comment: Yes. How is URL routing handled? IE: Can I route `^upload/anon/[a-zA-Z0-9]{32}$` to Tornado and everything else to Django seamlessly?

Comment: Hmm. Possible, but it'd require a bit more work. You'd have to specifically hand off requests for any URL the Tornado server didn't care about the the WGSI container for Django.